2009 Honda CRV - Where did the coolant go?
2009 Honda CRV with about 195,000 miles on it.
Here's the story:

the car overheated while driving on local roads. It made a groaning noise and then the temperature gauge spiked. It might be a red herring, but the A/C started blowing hot air around the same time. There has never been a visible leak of any sort from this vehicle.

took it to our regular mechanic to check out. They found that the coolant was low "about a couple cups" and the radiator cap was broken. They replaced the radiator cap, did a pressure test of the cooling system (negative), and concluded that it might be the early stages of a leaking head gasket.

took it to another mechanic. They did another pressure test, a test for the presence of coolant outside the cylinder heads (I think), and also removed the spark plugs & inspected inside the cylinders. All negative.


Since all this transpired, we have not driven the car too much -- a few short trips around town, checking regularly to make sure the coolant levels were OK.
At this point, the best hypothesis (I think) is that the radiator cap was not sealed and the coolant evaporated, leading to a low coolant level.
Is this a plausible explanation? Or can someone suggest another possible cause for disappearing coolant?

It's plausible to theorize that the coolant loss was caused by the broken radiator cap, but if the cooling system was low by just "a couple of cups", I don't think there's any way that would cause overheating in and of itself.
A 50-50 mix of ethylene glycol antifreeze and water can boil at about 225F at atmospheric pressure, i.e., with a broken radiator cap. With a working 15 psi radiator cap, the boiling point goes up to about 265F.
If this were my car, I would have removed and tested the thermostat to confirm that it's opening and closing at the right temperature, and not stuck closed. Since I gather that you are using a mechanic, it would have been prudent and appropriate to have them replace the thermostat rather than test it, since testing will cost additional labor and thermostats themselves are pretty inexpensive.
Thermostats are a "wear" item, and if this one has 195K miles on it, you owe the car a thermostat anyway. I'm not one for replacing anything without proof that it's defective, but in this case (with a mechanic on the clock), I'd have no problem replacing it instead of testing it.
A stuck-closed thermostat will overheat the engine, and when steam starts to form, there can be a groaning sound or strange thuds. The escape of steam into a cooler part of the engine can create pressures that can un-stick the thermostat and end the episode of overheating.
If you had your A/C balanced somewhere between warm and cold, the sudden circulation of super hot water to the heater core could have tipped the balance toward warm to hot.
So maybe a sticking thermostat and a broken radiator cap allowed the coolant to boil and the engine to overheat. If this is what happened, the thermostat could stick closed again any time. Or not.
Before you take any long trips or drive into any sketchy areas of town, maybe discuss it with your trusted regular mechanic and see if you both agree that a thermostat replacement would be prudent, especially if it has never been changed. The mechanic may tell you that failing thermostats usually stick "open", and this is true, resulting in a cold-running engine. But they do stick closed sometimes.

While the loss of a couple cups of coolant shouldn't have caused it to overheat, if the cap was not holding pressure, a steam pocket could have occurred causing the spike in temps on the dashboard.
